# Azure Function slow HTTP requests compared to when running in localhost

Tags: azure, performance, azure-functions, httpclient

I'm using a Azure Function .Net 6 Isolated.

When I run the function on localhost from VS2022, it is 5 times faster then when I deploy it to Azure Function. Localhost is a VM hosted in Azure in the same region as the function.
I tried different Service Plans, but issue remains. (Consumption Plan, Elastic Premium EP3, Premium V2 P3v2)

[image: The same code running in localhost Vs. Azure]

Results in different regions vs. localhost:
[image]

The code is as follows:

DI - using the IHttpClientFactory ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)):

```
public static class DataSourceServiceRegistration
{        
   public static IServiceCollection RegisterDataSourceServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
   {
       serviceCollection.AddHttpClient();
       return serviceCollection;
   }
}
```

HttpClient usage:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public EsriHttpClientAdapter(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
}

public async Task<JsonDocument> SendPrintServiceMessage(string url, HttpMethod httpMethod, string referer, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> content = null)
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    HttpContent httpContent = null;
    if (content != null)
    {
        httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);
    }
    var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, url) { Content = httpContent };
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri(referer);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("some", "config");

    _logger.LogInformation($"Before SendAsync - time {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
    _logger.LogInformation($"After SendAsync - time {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation($"After ReadAsStringAsync - time {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //do some stuff here
    }
}
```

Application Insights is as follows:

AZURE:

[image]

Localhost:

[image]

Comment: can you instrument the azure function running on Azure with App Insights? It will show you where is the bottleneck and you can optimize. From what I see, the issue may be in the code you hide (//do some stuff here)

Comment: Has it got anything to do with where your local desktop is and where the azure app geographically located as compared to the hosting of the http endpoint? Are you reading some DB in the hidden code? If yes, where is the DB hosted?

Comment: @AnupamChand The 'local' desktop is a VM also hosted in Azure. But its the same for both VM and local machine it performs well, when i run it in localhost.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thank four your help. Please see my update. The time is used between "Before SendAsync" and "After SendAsync". So it must have something to do with the HttpClient or the Network in Azure.

Comment: Is the region of the local VM and the the azure function the same ? If you are using a Vm as your local host then you are using the same azure network as the azure function and hence the problem can't be with the azure network .

Comment: @AnupamChand Thank four your help. Yes, the VM is in a different Network. To verify this is not the issue, I deployed the function to a Student subscription, but the result was the same. The function hosted in Azure took 5 times longer. I think it's a network issue on Azure too, but how I can find the bottleneck?

Comment: Did you verify if the local host VM and the function are deployed in the same region?

Comment: @AnupamChand Thank you. Yes VM and Function are in the same region. I set up a function in US central region, with the same results.

Comment: Did you manage to find the issue?

Comment: No, not yet. Do you have same issues?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable to you, but hopefully it helps. If you're running under a Basic (Consumption) plan, your function will always be cold and need to spin up when being invoked by Http trigger. To circumvent this, you can set the function to Always On (if this is within your budget and scope) if on App Service Environment, Dedicated, or Premium plans.  (In other words, Free Functions will always run cold.)

You can change this under Configuration > General Settings > Always On.

There's good info on how a Function runs through a cold startup at:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/

Comment: Thank or your help. But I think this is not the issue. The theory with the consumption plan would be right, when only the first few requests  is slow. But all requests are slow. And anyway, I tried it with 'always on' in the Premium V2 P3v2. And also functions running in Elastic Premium EP3 do not have a cold start.

Comment: No worries - sorry this didn't fix it for you.